# How to move files to folders based on the similarity of filenames in python

Tags: python, file, directory

I have many files, for example like this:

[image]

I want to move these files into folders according to their similar names, for example:
`_form into the _form folder`,
`_gallery into the _gallery folder`,
`75_gallery into the 75_gallery folder`, and
`75_gallery_from_home to 75_gallery_from_home folder`.

I'm trying to understand that the files are the same until before the `_number` part appears, I don't know how to split the filenames and then move them to their respective folders. kindly help me

Comment: you can use regex to do that !

Comment: Regex? Ok thanks, I'll try to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to extract the corresponding folder names, create the folders and also to move files into the folders in one go.

```py
import os
import re
import shutil

pattern = "_[0-9]+"

file_names = os.listdir(".")
for file_name in file_names:
    split = re.split(pattern, file_name)

    if len(split) == 1:
        print(f"Cannot extract the corresponding folder name from file {file_name}.")
    else:
        folder_name = split[0]
        
        if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
            os.mkdir(folder_name)

        shutil.move(file_name, os.path.join(folder_name, file_name))
```

The regex pattern allows you to split the filename on the first underscore that is followed by any number.

Comment: Wait, why is it that simple? like magic to me! And if you don't mind, I want to ask, what is the function of split which ends up being split[0]?

Comment: aaa, I just got it, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below as a starting point for your solution. Assuming you have excluded the file extension and just have filename in a variable, the below code shows how to use `regex` to get the initial part of filename so that you
can frame the folder name to move the file to.

```
import re

filename = "75_gallery_2686WYWENDD"
x = re.split("_", filename)
str=''
for k in x:
    if(re.search("^[0-9][0-9]",k)):
        if(len(k)>2):
            #ignore this part of file name
            print('ignoring ' + k)
        else:
            str = str + k
    else:
        str = str + '_' + k
print('folder name : ' + str)
```

Comment: aaa, after reading it a few times, i'm starting to get the idea you mean. I'll try to figure out how to create a folder and loop through all the files I have, thanks for the help and explanation.

Comment: In the below answer, you fill find how to create the folders programmatically too.